# CSRF Token Missing Python Flask

Tags: python

Hello I'm new to python flask web development. I've been wondering what's wrong with my code, I kept on getting CSRF Token Missing. I am using Flask-WTF version 0.11. There are instances where the validation was successful and when I try to click again the upload button, it just reloads or sometimes pops out a `CSRF Token Missing` string above my Text Field. This is only happening when I access in a different domain, it works on my localhost:

This is my partial code for config.py:

```
class Config:
    WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = True
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY') or 'hard to guess string'
```

This is my code for login.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

{% block title %}Chase POS - Login{% endblock %}

{% block page_content %}
<div class="page-header">
    <h1>Login</h1>
</div>
{{ form.hidden_tag() }}
<div class="col-md-4">
    {{ wtf.quick_form(form, method="POST", enctype="multipart/form-data") }}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

This is my code for views.py:

```
@main.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(id=form.id.data).first()
        if user is not None and user.verify_password(form.password.data):
            try:
                login_user(user, False)
                upload_file()
                return redirect(url_for('.login'))
            except ValueError:
                flash('Row ' + str(counter) + ': Incorrect value detected.')
            except TypeError:
                flash('Row ' + str(counter) + ': Data type mismatch. Failed to continue transaction.')
            except AttributeError:
                flash('Row ' + str(counter) + ': Some of the data cannot be found on the database.')
        else:
            flash('Invalid username or password.')
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)
```

I even tried to disable csrf but still get the same error. Hope you can help me, thanks in advance

Comment: try replace `{{ form.hidden_tag() }}` to `<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>`, look into http://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/csrf.html

Comment: I got an error `UndefinedError: 'csrf_token' is undefined` :(

Comment: How did you disable it ? `WTF_CSRF_CHECK_DEFAULT = False` ?

Comment: Yes, also tried WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = False but still not working

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with `flask` and `wtform`. Adding `CsrfProtect(app)` solved it for me.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_wtf.csrf import CsrfProtect
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'very secret'
CsrfProtect(app)
```

In the template, do:

```
{{ form.hidden_tag() }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `form.hidden_tag()` with `form.hidden_tag`. Alternatively, revert back to an older version of Flask-WTF (v0.9) where they still use the brackets in `form.hidden_tag()`